# Hills in a topdown game

Tags: 2d, rpg, terrain

I'm making a top down rpg game and was wondering if it was possible to show hills on a map instead of having everything completely flat. I've thought about changing to an isometric view, but if it can be avoided, I would rather do top down. How would I do this? Would I draw the tiles on an angle or something? Or is not possible without switching levels like in dwarf fortress?

Comment: By map you mean the actual level right? Hills have shades indicating their slopes. You could slow down players when they walk over it ( depending on the slopes direction )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're not looking to create layers, or do Isometric, my best idea would to create something similar to a topographic map. The higher the mountain, the darker it gets, and possibly adds distinct features based on your environment (Eg: Add snow the closer to the top).

Answer (score 22):

Look at one of the classic-style Zelda games. You can create the illusion of hills by using cliff faces.

[image]

Comment: Also it doesn't matter if the perspective is off, as long you make your gameplay tight and awesome!

Comment: Your gonna get the populist badge :)

Comment: It's weird. I keep getting the most votes on my shortest answers. The longer, more detailed ones get me hardly anything.